# double underflow in statistical functions (CDF of normal distribution)

Tags: java, statistics, double, normal-distribution, underflow

I am using CDF of a normal distribution in my project in Java, but I will very often encounter very small numbers when I calculate the CDF of a very small interval which are very far away from the mean. (e.g. cdf(-10000.02, -10000.01) for a normal distribution with mean 1000, std 0.1). That will cause underflow of double because the smallest number 64 bit double can handle is merely e-308 or so. 
I googled but failed to find packages that can handle this.

```
    import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution;
    public class NormalDistributionTest{
        public static double CDF(double start, double end, double mean, double stdDev){
            //NormalDistribution is from org.apache.commons.math3
            NormalDistribution nd = new NormalDistribution(mean, stdDev);       
            double p = nd.probability(start, end);
            return p;
        }
        static public void main(){
            System.out.println(NormalDistributionTest.CDF(-12.04, -12.03,6.62, 0.41));
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Peng Du

Comment: Could you add some code?!